# Is it possible to detect arrows hitting a specific area in rec room?

Tags: rec-room

I want to create a shooting game where you have to hit a specfic surface/plane with an arrow. I already tried a trigger volume but it does not detect the arrow flying through at all.

Is there a circuit or another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As of yet, arrows are projectiles, and so far do not have any chips for them.

However, if you can create your targets as custom AI bots with like 1 health or so, then it is a temporary workaround until the chips can notice arrows.